# Cant transfer file from remote server to local folder

Tags: php

I have an issue using this code to transfer files from a remote server to my computer's drive c folder.

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.affiliatewindow.com/logos/1961/logo.gif');
file_put_contents('C:/myDir/myFile.gif', $file);
```

Any workaround about this?

Comment: try [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: You have to provide information about errors from the screen/logs/etc.  Having an "issue" is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change the slashes (/) in to backslashes (\) in the `file_put_contents` function.
You can also try the function `realpath`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php

Another reason is, that the PHP File don't have the permission to write directly on the C drive.